# Problem with SimpleXML

Tags: php, xml, simplexml

I have the following xml code in my xml:

```
<features>
<pool type="inground">yes</pool>
<heating type="other"/>
</features>
```

However, if I do a print_r on my simplexml after parsing the xml, the pool element is set up like a string instead of the heating element which is an object. i.e

```
[pool] => yes
[heating] => SimpleXMLElement Object
        (
            [@attributes] => Array
                (
                    [type] => other
                )

        )
```

And so the following code to get the type of the pool:

```
$type = $pool->attributes()->type
```

fails giving a fatal error -> member method on non object.

What's the solution here?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `echo $features->pool['type'];` http://codepad.org/Eu1uMkgI

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're looking to access the attributes of the `pool` tag, you need to descend to it first:

```
$s = '  <features>
    <pool type="inground">yes</pool>
    <heating type="other"/>
    </features>
';
$pool = simplexml_load_string($s);
var_dump($pool->pool->attributes()->type);
```

That seems to work; it returns this for me:

```
object(SimpleXMLElement)#3 (1) {
  [0]=>
  string(8) "inground"
}
```

Comment: i'd use this if it was an isolated case, but my xml is full of tags like this, i really don't want to manually do this on every tag of my xml...

Comment: Would this work if Pool was setup like `<pool type='inground' />` too?

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use current reading style. You have to use as bellow

```
$xmlLoad = file_get_contents($XML_FILE);
$xml = new SimpleXMLElement($xmlLoad);
echo $xml->features->heating->attributes()->type;
```

Answer (score 0):

try this ?

```
foreach ($pool->children() as $child)
{
  $type = (string) $child->attributes()->type;
}
```